# How to gray out and disable a key in the keyboard in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ios-keyboard-extension

I am trying to gray out and disable keys in the keyboard that comes up when a user clicks a UITextField. Ideally, the key would turn gray and be 'disabled' when the user holds the button down. Is this possible?

I have been able to disable some keys programatically (though it is not grayed out). Here is how I did so with the backspace key (which you would never use in my application anyway):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let  char = string.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")

    if (isBackSpace == -92) {

        return false
    }
    ....
}
```

If this is not possible, will I have to make a keyboard specifically for my application to achieve this?

Comment: The code you posted does not detect the backspace key. When the user taps the backspace key, `string` will be the empty string. And no, there is no way to disable keys on the keyboard. You would need you own custom keyboard for that.